# Scratch card algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm

I'm a computer science student, and we have a small project to reverse engineer scratch card results as efficiently as possible.

We generate a random prize, out of our "pay table" and then we need to reverse engineer a winning/losing scratch card as a result.

This is my solution so far, however I think it's not very efficient.

For example, a card needing *X* matching symbols to be a "winner".

First I check if the card "won" or not, then I generate a random prize.
Then I create a "symbol array", and I fill it up.

If it's a winner, I first select a random symbol and put in *X* symbols.

Then I fill the rest of the "symbol array" with random symbols (not the winning one) with a random of 1 to *X* - 1 until the array is filled.

Finally, I randomly place all the symbols on my card.

Now this obviously works - but I want to make it even more efficient.

Any ideas would be highly welcomed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach seems quite efficient. However, you can probably improve performance by generating sets of losing symbols up front (or the first time you need them) and reusing them.